# Confusion on してもらって and the subject of this sentence

Tags: word-choice

Here is my sentence, `この前の俺と一緒にしてもらっては困る`.

I'm having some difficulty figuring out it's meaning. This sentence was said aloud by a male character to a female character. Just before he said this, he had gotten the girl to agree to let him tutor her but she asked him one more question to see if he were truly smarter than her and he got it incorrect. Thus, she now refuses to let him tutor her.

I assume この前の to mean "the thing before this" or "the thing that just happened". That's why I gave the background information last paragraph. I believe the subject of the sentence to be "you/the girl" since the speaker says together with himself. Next, I would think してもらって would be some sort of receiving of an act of doing. The subject, the girl, received something that they did together. And lastly, as for this, the speaker is troubled by this.

I feel like this sentence is largely context based, but I am not 100% sure so I apologize if I've left out any crucial details. I think this sentence is basically saying that the speaker is trouble by what just happened between them. I'm not sure why してもらって is used though. In the て form nonetheless.  The subject, the girl, would be the one doing the receiving and I'm confused on what type of act she received.

Any help would be much appreciated. I apologize if I'm sort of all over the place with this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While もらう usually has a connotation of someone doing something positive for the speaker, this is not always the case.

[コトバンク「貰う」⑨㋒](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%B2%B0%E3%81%86-646791#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)  **他人の行なった行為によって、自らが迷惑を受ける意を表す。** 「無断で入って－・っちゃ困るな」
**Expresses annoyance caused by the actions of others.** "Don't come in without permission."

**一緒にする** has a definition of **'to confuse with'.** [Weblio (2)](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

The English version of the manga translates this line as, *'You had better not assume I'm the same Futaro Uesugi you knew before.'*, which seems quite adequate.

[この前の俺]と[一緒にしてもらっては][困る]。
(The me from before) (confuse me with) (it's an annoyance/trouble)
A slightly more literal translation than the one provided in the manga might be: 'You'll regret it if you confuse me with who I was before.'

Here are a few other sentences that I've found using ～てもらっては困る:

> 酔って軍律を乱してもらっては困る。
>   Don't get drunk and break military protocol (as it would be trouble).
>
> ---
>
> この事はめったにしゃべってもらっては困るよ。
>   Be sure and keep your mouth shut about this.
>
> ---
>
> 絶対に勘違いしてもらっては困るので繰り返します。
>   If you misunderstand it will absolutely be an issue (trouble), so I'll repeat it again.
>
> ---
>
> 見くびってもらっては困る。
>   Don't patronize (look down on) me.

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for the edit;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the detective work on the manga I was reading. I did not know English manga were so far off with their wordage. Anyway I think you may need an edit as you said "一緒に has a definition of 'to confuse with'". Shouldn't this be  一緒にする? Thank you for clearing things up though.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this male met the female before (say, 3 days ago) and he gave her the impression that he is not smart enough to tutor her. Then, she gives him the second chance to prove he is smart enough to be a tutor... but he failed.

He probably studied the subject after the 'last event'. So he said "**I don't want you to consider I'm not smart enough to be your tutor like the last time.**"

Following is the breakdown of the sentence:

"この前" is like "the other day". It's past but not a long time before. Though in this case he points out the 'last event'.

"一緒にしてもらって" is originally "一緒にする". It means "put them together" or in this context "consider the same (degree of smartness as last time)".
In this case the girl considers that the boy is not smart enough. So it turns to "一緒にしてもらう". It is a polite way of expressing the passive voice.
Also he wants to say "困る" afterwards, so it turns to "一緒にしてもらっては".

Another example:

> I don't want you to come (来てもらっては困る).
>   "来る" → "来てもらう" → "来てもらっては"

The direct translation of "困る" is "worry", though it is also a round-about way of saying "I don't want you to do ..." or "Don't do ...".

I'm sorry about my English its not my mother tongue. I hope it gives you some idea.

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for the edit!